# Uniswap V3 pools for Ethereum

Tags: solidity, uniswap, uniswapv3

My current understanding is when we want to get `Dai` to `USDC` liquidity, we pass the addresses like so

```
UniswapV3Factory.getPool(Dai_address, USDC_address, poolFee);
```

But How should we get `ETH` to `DAI` liquidity pool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tokens pairs are between two ERC20 and the ETH is not an ERC20 token instead it is native currency to the ethereum blockchain.

After UNISWAP V2, uniswap added WETH(wrapper ether).

You can think of Wrapper ether as ERC20 varient of ether.

Every WETH is backed by one normal ETH.

[image]

Look at the image above, I have created DAI/ETH token pair but in the dynamic nft the pair is DAI/WETH.

Everytime you create a pair with ETH, there will be an internal swap between ETH and WETH.

Here's the [transaction](https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0xca40fe1d6210d118c2af601daaec448c97b9b4e75ee850106c51aed83c3f3570).

And you can read more about [WETH](https://weth.io/) here.

So to get ETH/DAI liquidity pool, you need to use WETH address.

```
UniswapV3Factory.getPool(Dai_address, WETH_address, poolFee);
```

Here's [WETH](https://etherscan.io/token/0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2) address in ethereum.

Tell me if it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Well that pair wouldnt be ETH->DAI, it would be WETH -> DAI instead.